# download zipped rss to memory - then unzip and parse in memory

Tags: ios, zip, nsdata

I'm working on an app that downloads a zipped rss feed and then unzips that file and parses the feed to SQLite. That works so far.

I fetch the zip this way:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.me.de/feed.zip"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I wonder if it's possible to directly unzip from NSData to an in-memory representation of the rss feed that can be parsed. The unpacked feeds have a memory footprint of about 1MB which shouldn't be an issue.
I'm hoping to get a better performance this way.

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

- https://github.com/mwaterfall/ZipKit for managing zip files,
- https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser for RSS feed parsing,

hopefully that should make things easier.